# MySQL statement becomes corrupt during query excution

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm making Wordpress custom page with php. When I execute query, it gives error below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '��brand VARCHAR(70),serialCode VARCHAR(70),QRCodeAddress VARCHAR(70),email VAR' at line 1

As you can see, you can see strange char � that usually happens from encoding problem. But what I wonder is that if I echo my sql statement, it has no any problem. Look bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE SerialTable(id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,brand 
VARCHAR(70),serialCode VARCHAR(70),QRCodeAddress VARCHAR(70),email VARCHAR
(70),sex VARCHAR(70),age VARCHAR(70),purchasePath VARCHAR(70),expiryDate 
VARCHAR(70),registeredDate VARCHAR(70),modelName VARCHAR(70),colorCode VARCHAR
(70))
```

And it even works well if I excute in MySql shell.

**My procedure is like this:**

1. I'm reading `UTF-8` `csv` file to read table column information
2. Depending on `csv` file information, make SQL statement like above and save it in variable `$sqlStr`
3. when i echo `$sqlStr`, it has no any syntax error and even works in MySql shell.
4. But when `$wpdb->query($sqlStr)`, it give error like above.
5. I tried to use `mysqli_query($conn, $sqlStr)` as well. and it give same error.

**MySql server info:**

Of course connection is localhost as long as web server and mysql server is on same computer.

```
MySql server collation : utf8_general_ci
mysql server charset : latin_swedish_ci
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for more than 48 hours and am completely stuck?

Comment: My php file is saved in eclipse with encoding MS949(same as CP949??).

Comment: Why not use utf-8 in eclipse ?

Comment: Strange thing is that before this SQL statement, I have more than 10 SQL statements which are already well excuted. such as $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE SerialTable1");
  $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE SerialTable1 LIKE SerialTable");
  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO SerialTable1 (SELECT * FROM SerialTable)");
  $sqlstr = "SELECT UpdatedTime FROM TableUpdateInfo WHERE TableName='SerialTable'";

Comment: I just tried to save php file in UTF-8 in eclipse. But it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Can you check your hidden characters ( whits spaces ) in eclipse ( Window>Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors  )

Comment: @S.Visser. there is no any hidden strange character.

Comment: There does not appear to be anything wrong with what you have above. I just executed this with some code and it created the table?

Comment: I solved problem. It embarrassed me. Cause was CSV file... OTL..... After I re-save csv file from excel, problem is gone... Sorry guys and thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that your CSV file contains "unprintable" characters that allow it to look normal within an editor.

Try deleting the offending line or lines and recreate them.